# How to set Print Design as default View in Word using Microsoft.Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I have a Word document that it's filled with HTML code and I have seen that everytime I open this document the default View is "Web Design" and I would like to knowh if there is anyway to set "Print Design" as default View.

I am usign Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word libraries under Asp. NET Enviroment (C#).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If  `oWordDoc` is a instance of a Word Document try:

```
oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View = WdViewType.wdPrintView
```

Comment: I think that the correct sentence is: documentoWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView; because View is ReadOnly property, but anyways this doesn't work. This document is send to the user in the client side...